# (lattices) image of $\Gamma''$ in $\Gamma/p\Gamma$

Tags: lattice-orders, quotient-group

While I was reading a proof, there's a line that I couldn't quite understand. Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice and $\Gamma'$ a sublattice of $\Gamma$ of index $p^{n+1}$. The statement i don't understand is the following:

If $\Gamma'$ is not contained in $p\Gamma$ then the image of $\Gamma'$ in $\Gamma/p\Gamma$ is of order $p$.

I can kind of see why this is true but I don't know how to prove it rigorously. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Could you give us a link of what you were reading? Usually this helps.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I was reading Serre's A Course in Arithmetic, p.99

Comment: There I read the following: "We have two cases: i) $\Gamma''$ is not contained in $p\Gamma$. Then $c=0$ and $a$ is the number of lattices $\Gamma'$, intermediate between $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma''$, and of index $p$ in $\Gamma$; such a lattice $\Gamma'$ contains $p\Gamma$. In $\Gamma/p\Gamma$ the image of $\Gamma'$ is of index $p$" -- I think, you have confused $\Gamma'$ and $\Gamma''$.

Comment: but after that it says "and it caontains the image of $\Gamma''$ which is of order $p$. (just to avoid the confusion, $\Gamma''$ in the book is $\Gamma'$ in my question.)